# How to restart a CABasicAnimation after it is completed

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I have a button and when pressed it runs a CABasicAnimation in 2 seconds. The first time I press the button the animation runs fine and the layer is filled red. The second time I press the button the animation doesn't run again. The red layer disappears because I remove it but it doesn't start back from the beginning again.

In the code below the basicAnimation is a class property. I also tried creating it inside the buttonPressed method itself which made no difference and then I tried adding it as an optional `var basicAnimation: CABasicAnimation?`, instantiating it inside the buttonPressed method, then setting it to nil inside the `animationDidStop(_:finished:)` delegate method but neither worked.

Why doesn't is run again?

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
// var basicAnimation: CABasicAnimation? // I tried this

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 100, startAngle: -.pi/2, endAngle: 3 * .pi/2, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

@objc func buttonTapped() {

    // basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd") // I tried this
    // let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd") // I also tried this
    removeAnimation()

    basicAnimation.delegate = self
    basicAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
    basicAnimation.fromValue = 0
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(2)
        
    basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "myAnimation")
}

func removeAnimation() {
    shapeLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "myAnimation")
}

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    print("animation done") // prints once

    // basicAnimation = nil // I tried this
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make your code work just by making a new animation each time the button is tapped:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

var basicAnimation: CABasicAnimation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 100, startAngle: -.pi/2, endAngle: 3 * .pi/2, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    removeAnimation()

    basicAnimation.delegate = self
    basicAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
    basicAnimation.fromValue = 0
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(2)
        
    basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "myAnimation")
}

func removeAnimation() {
    shapeLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "myAnimation")
}

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    print("animation done")
}
```

[image]

Comment: There are other things wrong with your code, however. But you didn't ask about them so I haven't bothered to discuss them. :)

Comment: I c+p your code (which is exactly like my code) and it's not doing what yours is doing. I must have a problem somewhere else, hmmmmm. I even added **print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(basicAnimation!).toOpaque())** and a different memory address prints every time. Very strange

Comment: Well, if there’s an issue, it’s outside the code you showed. Would you be persuaded if I posted the whole test project?

Comment: You was correct, there was gesture recognizer that was causing the problem. Once I removed it the animation worked fine. Much appreciated and thanks for letting me know that animations can't be reused. Very helpful :)